# MySQL - Query failed from workbench /application with Error code: 2013 lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

We have query with large amount of data.
We are running query from workbench or application (java application) but not showing result.
error:

> Error code:2013 lost connection to MySQL server during query
> but failed query regarding process showing DB server side

- MySQL server version: 5.6.43-log

We have change below parameter values.

- connect_timeout - 28800
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout   - 600
- net_read_timeout 1200
- net_ite_timeout 1200
- wait_timeout 28800
- max_allowed_packet 6710886

Workbench setting:

- DBMS connections timeout interval - 10000.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Issue, few queries which are taken more than 1hr to execute on the MySQL server. The same query run on workbench it is not showing the result.
The workbench is going hung and error showing is lost connection.Please let me know what details required from myside